# Wordpress Database with custom table

Tags: php, database, wordpress

I am trying to pull data from a table I have imported into my wordpress database.

My php code works for all the default wp_ tables but when try and target the tables I actually want I get bugger all back.

My code (currently echoing all post titles and it works)

```
$liveposts = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts
 WHERE post_status = 'publish'") );

 foreach ($liveposts as $livepost) {
  echo '<p>' .$livepost->post_title. '</p>';
}
```

I imported 3 tables from another database, and yes they do have data in to pull out. I found out that the `$wpdb->posts` expects the posts table to be wp_posts.. so I tried renaming my tables to wp_bus_route... but still nothing.

I used phpMyAdmin to export 3 tables out of a large database (in a .sql format) and imported them. i can see the tables in phpMyAdmin and view all the data in them.

This is my 1st time pulling data from the wp database so I am missing something obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to not using variables at table names:

```
$liveposts = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM wp_bus_route
 WHERE post_status = 'publish'") );
```

Comment: Cool, that has done the trick thanks :) Any thoughts on why this works and $wpdb-> does not?
And what is the diffence between $wpdb->bus_routes and wp_bus_routes?

Comment: It's because wordpress has $tables build in variable described in wp-includes/wp-db.php, where described alloweb tables names array( 'posts', 'comments', 'links', 'options', 'postmeta',
  'terms', 'term_taxonomy', 'term_relationships', 'commentmeta' ); if you add to this array bus_routes it would work but whatever after wordpress updates to the newer version all your changes will be lost, so use static names of tables instead variables

Comment: ok thanks for the insight. makes sense in my head now :)
cheers guys

Answer (score 7):

Referencing the table name like `$wpdb->posts` only works for standard WP tables. For custom tables, build the table name like this:

```
$liveposts = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM " . $wpdb->prefix . "tablename WHERE post_status = 'publish'") );
```

Never, never, never hard-code the prefix. This can be changed in wp-config.php, and many people change it to something other than `wp_`. Changing it from `wp_` is a good security measure. Even if it's your own code and your own site, `$wpdb->prefix` is a best practice that's worth making into a habit.