# Wordpress custom query

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, ezsql

I have a wordpress blog. I created a db table which stores dictionary information and I want to publish this data from a URL . (For ex: "myblogaddress.com/mytest.php")

I have been researching for 2 days but nothing works I tried.

In my page; I use the php code shown in blow.

```
<?php
global $wpdb;
   $words = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->words")

echo $words[0]->ENG;


?>
```

I wonder that;
 - Which directory does my php page to be into ?
 - What I need to do (other config, permission etc.) to do what I want.

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're loading it from a standalone PHP file (ie not from within your WordPress theme), you'll have to call `wp-load.php` to initialise the WordPress variables (including `$wpdb`).  Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306612/using-wpdb-in-standalone-script/5331944#5331944), including the comment about only needing `wp-load.php`.

I'd consider using a relative path (what that would be would depend on where you put your page relative to WordPress) rather than using `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];`, but that's just a personal preference.

**EDIT**

Rereading after seeing your comment, I've just realised `$wpdb->words` probably won't exist.  Try

```
$words = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM " . $wpdb->prefix . "words")
```

instead.  That'll generate the table name correctly as `wp_words`.  Of course, you'll need to populate it the same way.

Comment: I am loading it in the theme. I can reach posts, users table and I can write some of columns of this tables using the query like shown in my question. I can not select the data which is into mycustom table named wp_words. Is there any way to reach custom tables in wp ?

Comment: Really thanks. Your answer solved my problem. That answer, too. --> http://stackoverflow.com/a/3387110/1172945